# Converting REST API response to a table

Tags: powershell

When I do a GET on a REST API enabled system the return is formatted as a table and displayed as this:

```
problems
--------
{@{problemID=8004; description=vCenter Server 6853d04d-4ff0-4eba-b0a2-4a7dffcaf028 is not licensed.; severity=WARNING; category=SYSTEM; relevantSplitter=; cluster=; relevantRPAs=System.Object[]; relevantGlobalLinks=System.Object[]; relevantCopies=System.Object[]; relevantDevices=System.Object[]; relevantSplitterVolumesInfor…
```

If I pipe it to Format-List I get:

```
problems : {@{problemID=8004; description=vCenter Server 6853d04d-4ff0-4eba-b0a2-4a7dffcaf028 is not licensed.; severity=WARNING; category=SYSTEM; relevantSplitter=; cluster=; relevantRPAs=System.Object[]; relevantGlobalLinks=System.Object[]; relevantCopies=System.Object[]; relevantDevices=System.Object[];
           relevantSplitterVolumesInformation=System.Object[]}, @{problemID=10100; description=At least one virtual RPA is running on the same ESX as the VM it is replicating. It is recommended not to have the virtual RPA that replicates a VM running on the same ESX as the replicated VM. Use vMotion to move one of them to
           another ESX.; severity=WARNING; category=CONSISTENCY_GROUP; relevantSplitter=; cluster=; relevantRPAs=System.Object[]; relevantGlobalLinks=System.Object[]; relevantCopies=System.Object[]; relevantDevices=System.Object[]; relevantSplitterVolumesInformation=System.Object[]}, @{problemID=10100; description=At least
           one virtual RPA is running on the same ESX as the VM it is replicating. It is recommended not to have the virtual RPA that replicates a VM running on the same ESX as the replicated VM. Use vMotion to move one of them to another ESX.; severity=WARNING; category=CONSISTENCY_GROUP; relevantSplitter=; cluster=;
           relevantRPAs=System.Object[]; relevantGlobalLinks=System.Object[]; relevantCopies=System.Object[]; relevantDevices=System.Object[]; relevantSplitterVolumesInformation=System.Object[]}}
```

I am trying to make the leap to taking the value for problems and use it as an array of hash tables which it appears to be. I guess I just have not connected the dots as yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7) on your output.

Comment: When I do that it errors out with: `Conversion from JSON failed with error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: @. Path '', line 0, position 0.`

Comment: Try it on the property `problems`. So `$object.problems | ConvertFrom-Json`. If that doesn't work, there may be a problem with the Json. You might need to post the full Json output string so we can see what you're trying to convert. Perhaps you need to show your code too to get the response.

Comment: I must be brain dead. I thought I had tried $results.problems but it returned nothing. Now it returns what I want. Thank you for the answer.